# create a separate database config file in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm using CakePHP 3.4

default database settings exists in `config/app.php`

I want to separate out or override database configuration outside app.php say in `config/my_db.php` and load it in `bootstrap.php` file.

This setting will now override default database setting that exists in `app.php` file.

Is there some way to do this ?

> Edit 2

**config/my.db.php** file

```
<?php
return [
    'my_db' => [
       'Datasources' => [
           'default' => [
               'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
               'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
               'persistent' => false,
               'host' => 'localhost',
               'username' => 'root',
               'password' => 'my_pass',
               'database' => 'testdb',
               'encoding' => 'utf8',
               'timezone' => 'UTC',
               'flags' => [],
               'cacheMetadata' => true,
               'log' => false,
           ]
       ]
    ]
];
```

**loading in bootstrap.php**

```
Configure::load('my_db', 'default', false);
```

Comment: change in bootstrap.php file just

Comment: https://securityblog.gr/1957/create-custom-configuration-files-in-cakephp-3/ ... Check it Out this..

Comment: what is my_db ???  and what is database => testdb  ???

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPS0zRAoVow ... check it out this

Comment: `my_db` is the name given to load in bootstrap file. `'database' => 'testdb'` is the name of the database

Comment: and file name in config file ??

Comment: `my_db.php` . Shared YouTube video is not relevant to my concern. It shows how to configure database settings. But, I have to separate database settings from `app.php` file

Comment: check my ans i update it ... You try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create **new file into folder config/**
2. Name it whatever you like: **my_db.php**
3. Add your code **configuration Code:**

return [

```
        'my_db' => [
            'setting_1'   =>  'value_1',
            'setting_2'   =>  'value_2',
            'setting_3'   =>  'value_3',
        ],
    ];
```

4. Now you have to load it. **Open file config/bootstrap.php,** 
   locate line:

   `Configure::load('app', 'default', false);`
5. and append this line underneath:

   **Configure::load('my_db', 'default');**

**Try THis ::**

> config/bootstrap.php

```
Configure::load('my_app', 'default','false');
```

> config/my_app.php

```
<?php

return [
       'Datasources' => [
           'default' => [
               'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
               'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
               'persistent' => false,
               'host' => 'localhost',
               'username' => 'root',
               'password' => 'my_pass',
               'database' => 'my_db',
               'encoding' => 'utf8',
               'timezone' => 'UTC',
               'flags' => [],
               'cacheMetadata' => true,
               'log' => false,
           ]
       ]
];
```

Comment: not working. still it is using database setting which is there in `app.php` file

Comment: See `Edit 2` in question

Comment: @AnujTBE ... I Just try to Expalin ...what is going on....  first .. Bootstrap.php file bootstrap the .. config/my_app.php file ... so inside my_app.php no need to  return this  my_db' => [ ....  ] just remove it first .. and then try it ..

Comment: Hey, it worked. Thanks. But can't I put `Configure::load('my_app', 'default');` in the last on `bootstrap.php` file. Because, doing so is giving error as `If config is null, key must be an array.` and when I add that like below `Configure::load('app', 'default', false);` block, then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

make a copy of your `app.php`, name it `app_override.php` and change your db-settings.

Then adapt your bootstrap.php like this

```
try {
    Configure::config('default', new PhpConfig());
    Configure::load('app', 'default', false);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage() . "\n");
}

Configure::load('app_override', 'default');
```